# Why a mask's background color changes when I set the window background color on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, window, calayer, mask

I do a twitter animation project as practice. I want to change the mask's background color, but I don't know why to set the window background color to change it.

Here is my code in AppDelegate

```
var mask: CALayer?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.mask = CALayer()
    self.mask?.contents = UIImage(named: "twitter")?.cgImage
    self.mask?.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
    self.mask?.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    self.mask?.position = self.window!.center

    self.window?.rootViewController?.view.layer.mask = self.mask
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 18/255, green: 145/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1) // Why?

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are masking the view that you add the mask to.  I.o.w.  You are masking `self.window?.rootViewController?.view`.

A mask, cuts out the area like a stencil, by using the alpha channels of the layer that it is applied to.  Therefor, `self.window?.rootViewController?.view`, will be 'cut' according to the mask that you apply.  Because `self.window?.rootViewController?.view` is directly on top of `self.window`, `self.window` will be visible at the cut out pieces.  If the backgroundColor was not set, you will see a black background, which is the default background color for the Window.  I hope this make sense.

Comment: Thank you, I figure out.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `backgroundcolor` for mask also but it is not `UIColor`, it should be `CGColor` something like,

```
  self.window?.rootViewController?.view.layer.mask!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 18/255, green: 145/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
```

Comment: It's not work. The mask change to a square and background still black.